# JQuery - Add class on click verifying ID

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, frontend

I'm trying to add a class to a specific element that contains a parent container with a unique ID.

I have several buttons contained in a div, and all of them are using the same classes. For some reason, I can't use only $(this), so I created a loop that adds a unique ID to the containers.

HTML

```html
<div class='section'>
 <div class='btn-container' id='btn-1'>
  <button class='btn'></button>
 </div>
 <div class='btn-container' id='btn-2'>
  <button class='btn'></button>
 </div>
 <div class='btn-container' id='btn-3'>
  <button class='btn'></button>
 </div>
</div>
```

JQuery

```js
$("button").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var target = $(e.target).parents(".button-container").attr("id");
  console.log(target);
  $(target).find(".btn").addClass("active");

});
```

I'm targeting the ID and it works, the console.log gives me back the correct info. However, for some reason, I can't add the class.

Thank you in advance for any help! (:

Edited:
I'm trying to add the class active to the button that is contained in the ID.

Example:
$("#btn-1 .btn").addClass("active"); but with the ID dynamically populate based on the info from the click.

Comment: do you want to add the class to the button or the parent div?

Comment: good call! I need to add the class to the button. So, I'm trying to do something like that: `$(ID .btn).addClass("active");`
Thank you!

Comment: Last line would be `$("#" + target)` - but you're getting the same thing twice.  So `var target = $(e.target).parents(".button-container");`  `target.find(".btn"...` - no need for the `id` or `.attr("id")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep things simple, this should work

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
  $("button").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $(e.target).addClass("active")

});
});
```

```css
.active{
  border: 1px red solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='section'>
 <div class='btn-container' id='btn-1'>
  <button class='btn'>Test</button>
 </div>
 <div class='btn-container' id='btn-2'>
  <button class='btn'>Test</button>
 </div>
 <div class='btn-container' id='btn-3'>
  <button class='btn'>Test</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can utilize `$(this)` instead of `$(e.target)` :: `$(this).addClass("active")` (More jQuery-ish)

Comment: As above: `e.target` is not always the same as `this`